# Is it possible to unpack a zip file over ssh?

Tags: ssh, zip

I have files in a .zip archive I want to upload to a remote server over ssh. I want to avoid uploading and then unzipping because the remote server has limited space.

I could unzip the archive locally and then upload the unzipped files. That seems wasteful and then I have to do some cleanup.

Ideally, I'd like the files that get unpacked from the archive to get sent directly to the remote server instead of saved to the local host. Is there a way to do this over ssh?

Comment: Mostly a dup of this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/how-to-redirect-output-of-wget-as-input-to-unzip

Comment: @yoonix zip is 'special' and doesn't work from stdin as easily because of the way the archive is formated. Not sure that superuser answer helps since it is mostly about tar archives.

Comment: Thanks. Following an example there, I just tried `ssh admin@example.org "unzip" < example_files.zip but it didn't work. Is there an example specific to zip archives?

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for schooling me.  Removed the invalid coment.

Comment: It looks like the unzip that's included with [busybox](https://busybox.net/) can handle stdin just fine.  If you can install that, you can run `busybox unzip -` on the ssh command line and it should work.  I think your idea of just moving to tar is a better option though.

Comment: only way I managed to do it a couple years ago when I had this problem was to extract the list of files and use `-p` on each of them in a script.  `-p` allows you to dump *one* file to stdout so the script does it one at a time.  Not an ideal long-term situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending stdin/stdout over ssh is covered elsewhere, but because that is tricky with zip files, here's an alternative with sshfs:

```
sshfs user@host /mnt/path
cd /mnt/path
unzip /tmp/foobar.zip
cd /
fusermount -u /mnt/path
```

Your mileage may very, because sshfs is has various problems.

If you can change your original files to something like gzip, which is one `gz` file per source file, that can easily be redirected over ssh, including fancy progress viewing with `pv`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Yeah, I think I'm just going to switch to tar archives instead.

Comment: Ugh. I actually have tools for stream-unpacking zip files but at several hundred MB, ...